# When should we use “Perfect infinitive” instead of “infinitive” in passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice, infinitives, perfect-aspect

I was doing exercises from great blue textbook when I met the difficult one. Please, explain me the difference between usage infinitive and present infinitive in passive voice.

Foe example:
Do you think that more money should ***be spent*** on education.

Why can’t we use perfect infinitive in this example?

Another one:

This road is in very bad condition. It should ***have been repaired*** a long time ago.

Does it wrong to use be repaired in this example?

Thank you!

Comment: The road should **have been repaired** a long time ago (Past tense).   The road should **be repaired** as soon as possible (Present tense).

Comment: @Kate 'should be repaired', isn't that some weird future conditional?

Answer (score 3):

With *should*, the past infinitive makes it counter-factual

"It should be repaired" is making a demand for the future, and says nothing about the past.

"It should have been repaired" is saying that it has not been repaired, and this was wrong. It does not specifically demand anything for the future: the speaker might still wish this, or it may now be too late to do anything.